# How to not display script name when looping on command line argument?

Tags: python

I am not familiar at all with Python. I am just trying to create a basic script where I would like to get all the command line argument without the script name.

When I do

```
for arg in sys.argv:         
        print arg
```

I get the following ouput :

```
<scriptname>
<arg1>
<arg2>
<argn>
```

So : How can I skip  the scriptname to appear in the output?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:         
    print arg
```

This is called [slicing](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html) and is supported for any list-like structure including strings. More examples:

```
>>> s = "Hello"
>>> s[1:]
'ello'
>>> s[:2]
'He'
```

Slicing also supports negative indices:

```
>>> s[:-1]
'Hell'
>>> s[:-2]
'Hel'
```